# EmberJS changing RESTAdapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm fairly new to EmberJS so this might be an easy one.  I just couldn't find an answer to date.

I have an API that I connect to that doesn't follow Ember convention and that I can't change.

I want to be able to delete a record.

The Ember convention would be    /people/123  using the DELETE HTTP Verb.

When I call person.deleteRecord()  I need it to be able to call a POST /people/destroy/123

Seems like overriding could be possible but unsure of the direction to take.